# Powershell Get-WinEvent $_.Properties[ ].value returns unexpected value

Tags: powershell

Using PS to go through some events. Looking for failed logons (4635), and then getting the relevant info.

I have something like:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{path=$path; id=$ID} | ? {$_.Properties[5].Value -match $user} |
Select-Object -Property TimeCreated, @{Name="AccountName"; Expression={$_.Properties[5].Value}}, @{Name="IP ADDRESS"; Expression={$_.Properties[19].Value}}, @{Name="LOGON"; Expression={$_.Properties[10].Value}}, @{Name="DOMAIN"; Expression={$_.Properties[6].Value}}, @{Name="STATUS"; Expression={$_.Properties[9].value}}  | 
Format-Table -Auto | Out-File temp.txt
```

Everything works fine, EXCEPT the `$_.Properties[9].value`. It is supposed to return some hex value (e.g. `0xc0000064`), but instead I get some negative integer, e.g. `-1073741718`

How do I get the hex code? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
.ToString('X2')
```

on an unsigned integer to output it as hex

You could device a function for this purpose

```
function int2hex
{
    param([int]$value)
    return "0x$($value.ToString('X2'))"
}
```